# How to only show dates before character /?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of ISO 8601 dates intervals (start and end date). how do you only select the dates before slash with javascript (start dates)?

```
var dates = [
2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00/2020-01-01T10:30:00.000+06:00,
2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00/2019-12-31T16:00:00.000-10:00
]
```

I would like the result to be

```
[2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00,2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00]
```

I tried this string-replace method,

```
let result = dates.replace(/\/.*/g, '');
```

but it replaces everything after the first bracket.

Answer (score 2):

The variables dates is an array, so you should iterate on this.

```js
var dates = [
'2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00/2020-01-01T10:30:00.000+06:00',
'2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00/2019-12-31T16:00:00.000-10:00'
]

// [2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00,2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00]

let result = dates.map(date => date.split('/')[0]);
console.log(result);
```

But be carefull, in your question, your dates variable is not an array of type string. Maybe it's an array of type Date...

Comment: the solution only gives me the very first date though. i need every start date - so 

2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00 and 2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00

Comment: Mmmh, are you sure it's type date? Because '2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00/2020-01-01T10:30:00.000+06:00' is invalid type date. By type date, I said output of something like `new Date()`.

Comment: Did you run code snippet? It output every start date in `console.log`.

Comment: Could you validate answer please?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to [**String.prototype.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead of `replace`. Make an iteration over the array using [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), in every cycle of the iteration split the element (`start date / end date`) and capture the `start date` as you expected.

```js
var dates = [
'2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00/2020-01-01T10:30:00.000+06:00',
'2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00/2019-12-31T16:00:00.000-10:00'
]

let results = dates.map(i => i.split('/')[0])

console.log(results)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    "2019-12-31T23:45:00.000-03:00",
    "2020-01-01T07:15:00.000+07:00"
]
```

Comment: doesnt the [0] only give the very first date? I need them both. my array has multiple intervals so i need all the start dates

Comment: Yes `[0]` gives only the first date of each element of the array.

Comment: so how do you get all dates before slash? not just the first date?

Comment: When you split by `/`, it return an array who's first index (`[0]`) is the start date you expected.

Comment: i dont expect first date.  I have 4 dates:
[start date / end date,
start date / end date]
and i need both start dates, not just the first start date

Comment: Did you run this codes? it gives you both start dates.

Comment: yes, it only gives me first date. i have to have something else wrong. thanks for help!

Comment: does it have to have quotes for it to work? my data comes from text file and doesnt have any quotes

Comment: Yes, you need a string quote.

Comment: I cant add the quotes to the file so this doesn't work for me